# Keras not showing progress bar when training model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to train a CNN to classify some images. I did that before with Keras on TF backend, worked like a charm. Now it doesn't want to show that progress dialog which shows accuracy and current epoch.

Here's the code of my CNN model:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 150, 3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))

classifier.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'images/train',
    target_size=(200, 150),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'images/test',
    target_size=(200, 150),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')


classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=5604, 
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=1831,
        verbose=1)
```

Is there something I'm missing?
All I see now is this:

Epoch 1/10

Thanks...

Comment: could it be that an epoch takes a long time to complete?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124676/show-progress-bar-for-each-epoch-during-batchwise-training-in-keras) help?

Comment: What do you see when it prints `Found x images belonging to y clases` ? if you see 0 images there, you should check your folders structure. Inside `train` you should have one folder for every class, and inside that folder the images. Same goes for the `test` folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show progress bar for each epoch during batchwise training in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124676/show-progress-bar-for-each-epoch-during-batchwise-training-in-keras)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sugestions. The problem was due to incorrect CudNN versions. Had to download the version from 2017 and now it works!