# How to get progress of current epoch during tf.keras training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a GUI application for training of various `tf.keras`-based models. So all the information on `accuracy`, `loss` etc. should be visible on the GUI instead of the default Keras console output.

Now I managed to get all the relevant information during model training via a custom `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` class, which works fine. But I also want to get the progress of the current epoch, i.e. how much % of the current epoch has been trained so far, i.e. what Keras prints to console during training via the progress bar.

Is there any way to retrieve that information in a Keras callback as well?

Comment: You should be able to infer that from `on_train_batch_begin` / `on_train_batch_end` in [`Callback`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) (and `test` callbacks if necessary), but you need to know how many batches are in each epoch.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, that is kind of my "plan B", but I was hoping for a better / more accurarte approach.

Comment: I'm not sure that is actually possible, you want to see the progress as a single batch is processed? TensorFlow does not provide that information, you give an input and eventually get an output, and it cannot "know" how many batches you have per epoch in the general case. You could try to be fancy and collect timings on each batch callback to have an estimation of how long each batch will take (e.g. with some kind of moving average) and report progress based on that... But I'm not sure that could possibly be worth the effort. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39124676).

Comment: @jdehesa Frankly I would be surprised if that is really the case. Think of the default console output during training. For each epoch you see a progress bar from 0 to 100% indicating how far the training of **that current** epoch is at the moment. So this information must be somewhere in Keras, right? Edit: As a last resort I could parse the console output from training and use that information ...

Comment: That's right, you can get the progress of an epoch, but it is always at batch (or, in Keras terms, "step") granularity. If an epoch has ten batches, you see a 10% increase for every step, but you cannot see the progress between 0% and 10%. As you put in your solution, dividing the current step by the number of steps per epoch is your best option.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the solution. It can be found in the `self.params` attribute of the `Callback` class.
For me this works:

```
def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    self.epoch_step = 0

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.epoch_step += 1
    progress = self.epoch_step / self.params["steps"]
```

For the reords, I found this solution [here in the `keras-tqdm` GitHub repo](https://github.com/bstriner/keras-tqdm/blob/master/keras_tqdm/tqdm_callback.py).